# php condition (in different value)

Tags: php

**php condition  (IN DIFFERENT VALUE)**

if  $tt > 29 print Good ,  if $tt < 55 print  Very good but when $tt= less than 0 print very bad in php

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read guidelines here: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: What is your question? How to make a condition? Have you tried [reading the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)? What code have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: You're looking for an `if elseif else` construction, look for it in the docs or on google. Lots and lots of documentation to find on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has too may loopholes and few numbers are overlapping your conditions and few are comming in no condition.

So here is a code which will print

1. very bad for number less than or equal to 0
2. bad for number 1 to 29
3. good for 30 to 55
4. very good for 55 and above

You can chenge number based on your needs

```
<?php
if( $tt <= 0 ) {
  echo "Very Bad";
} else if( $tt <= 29) {
  echo "Bad";
} else if( $tt <= 55) {
 echo "Good";
} else {
 echo "Very Good";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if( $tt > 29 ) {
 print "Good";
} else if( $tt > 29 &&  $tt < 55) {
 print "Very Good";
} else if( $tt < 0) {
 print "Very bad";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go**

```
 <?php
 if( $tt > 29 ) {
  echo "Greater Than 29 ";
 } else if( $tt > 29 &&  $tt < 55) {
       echo "Greater Than 29 and less than 55 ";
 } else if( $tt < 0) {
  echo "less than zero ";
 }
 ?>
```